# Error in the wp-config.php file: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unknown named parameter (PHP 8.0)

Tags: plugins, errors

I get the following error:

```
[06-Mar-2021 03:07:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Unknown named parameter $tasks_meta_id in /var/www/example.com/html/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:287
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/example.com/html/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#1 /var/www/example.com/html/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php(551): WP_Hook->do_action()
#2 /var/www/example.com/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/vendor/woocommerce/action-scheduler/classes/actions/ActionScheduler_Action.php(22): do_action_ref_array()
#3 /var/www/example.com/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/vendor/woocommerce/action-scheduler/classes/abstracts/ActionScheduler_Abstract_QueueRunner.php(65): ActionScheduler_Action->execute()
#4 /var/www/example.com/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/vendor/woocommerce/action-scheduler/classes/ActionScheduler_QueueRunner.php(162): ActionScheduler_Abstract_QueueRunner->process_action()
#5 /var/www/example.com/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/vendor/woocommerce/action-scheduler/classes/ActionScheduler_QueueRunner.php(132): ActionScheduler_QueueRunner->do_batch()
#6 /var/www/example.com/html/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): ActionScheduler_QueueRunner->run()
#7 /var/www/example.com/html/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#8 /var/www/example.com/html/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php(551): WP_Hook->do_action()
#9 /var/www/example.com/html/wordpress/wp-cron.php(138): do_action_ref_array()
#10 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/example.com/html/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 287
```

Can anyone please advise on this? I am using the wpforms plugin and even after I have disabled all plugins, I still have this error in the error log. Just for your information, [I have implemented this tutorial](https://tonyteaches.tech/send-smtp-email-from-wordpress/) to send emails without the STMP plugin. I receive emails and everything looks fine except that the theme shakes badly when I click on the menu links to navigate between pages and I am not sure what is the reason. When I checked the error logs to know why I saw the above error
I use PHP 8.0 and I only have two plugins installed. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the `plugins/wpforms-lite` plugin compatible with PHP 8?

Comment: @VincenzoDiGaetano No, it is not and this is the reason. I have confirmed this with them -That is the reason.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the plugin is incompatible with PHP8. I have contacted the developer and their advice is:

*At the moment, we are not quite ready with PHP 8 compatibility, but it is coming soon on the horizon. It looks like the specific issue you're having is related to PHP 8, so unfortunately you will need to have your server set to run PHP 7.X*

Update:
If you want to downgrade your PHP version from 8 to 7.4 for example, you can use [this article](https://webdock.io/en/docs/perfect-server-stacks/upgrade-or-downgrade-php/upgrading-or-downgrading-php-versions).